# MySQL customized group concat

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I need to convert my query result, so multiple row with same foreign key be just one row.
I can do that with grouping. the problem is that in one of my columns I want to concatenate some columns with different grouping.
for example my table contain somting like this:

```
shopId     Brand    Category    Color     QTY
----------------------------------------------
15         Dell     NoteBook    Red       5
15         Dell     NoteBook    Blue      1
15         HP       NoteBook    red       2
15         HP       NetBook     red       3
14         Sony     NoteBook    yellow    1
14         Acer     Tablet      red       10
```

Brand, Category and Color all retrieved from their foreign keys.
I want to present this result like

```
ShopId      Dell    Color             HP    Color    etc...
-----------------------------------------------------------
15          6       red:5, Blue:1     2     red:2    
14 ..............
```

in my query I grouped them by shopId and finding total qty for each brand and category by using sum and case statment was an easy job. my problem is how can I concatenate color and qty for shop,category,brand grouping (total grouping is by shopId not shop,category,brand)?

My tabale is

```
CREATE TABLE `shopstorage` (
 `color` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `brand` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `shop` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `qty` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`color`,`category`,`brand`,`shop`,`date`),
 KEY `clrEpClr` (`color`),
 KEY `clrEpCat` (`category`),
 KEY `clrEpshop` (`shop`),
 KEY `clrEpBrand` (`brand`),
 CONSTRAINT `SSBrand` FOREIGN KEY (`brand`) REFERENCES `brand` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `SSCat` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `productcategory` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `SSClr` FOREIGN KEY (`color`) REFERENCES `color` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `SSShop` FOREIGN KEY (`shop`) REFERENCES `shop` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and my incomplet query is

```
select 
    shop.name, shop.floor, shop.no, 
    sum(case when brand.name ='ASUS' and productcategory.name='NoteBook' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as ASUS,
    sum(case when brand.name ='HP' and productcategory.name='NoteBook' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as HP,
    sum(case when brand.name ='Sony' and productcategory.name='NoteBook' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as Sony,
    sum(case when brand.name ='Dell' and productcategory.name='NoteBook' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as Dell,
    sum(case when brand.name ='ASUS' and productcategory.name='NetBook' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as ASUS,
    sum(case when brand.name ='HP' and productcategory.name='NetBook' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as HP,
    sum(case when brand.name ='Sony' and productcategory.name='NetBook' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as Sony,
    sum(case when brand.name ='Dell' and productcategory.name='NetBook' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as Dell,
    sum(case when brand.name ='ASUS' and productcategory.name='Tablet' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as ASUS,
    sum(case when brand.name ='HP' and productcategory.name='Tablet' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as HP,
    sum(case when brand.name ='Sony' and productcategory.name='Tablet' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as Sony,
    sum(case when brand.name ='Dell' and productcategory.name='Tablet' then shopstorage.qty else 0 end) as Dell
from shopstorage 
    join brand on shopstorage.brand=brand.id
    join color on shopstorage.color=color.id
    join productcategory on shopstorage.category=productcategory.id
    join shop on shop.id = shopstorage.shop
group by shopstorage.shop
```

I am looking for a way to add a column after each sum for specifying each color qty for example if HP is 15 It have 7 red and 8 Blue Notebooks. I tried GROUP_Concat but it wasn't showing right result because of wrong grouping.

Comment: You want a "pivot". Search SO for that term

Comment: I already searched for that. but tanks :)

Comment: Show us your table structure (the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`) and your query so far.

Comment: @Jocelyn I added them to end of question

Comment: Smells a bit like trying to use SQL as a Turing-complete language again. Some stuff is better done in application code than in SQL. That is all. (i.e. you can achieve it, but it's not very flexible, thus maintenance might be complicated - application code can handle this more gracefully)

Comment: @Romain: I already achieved this by nested fors in my application. but my problem is that because this result must be joined to other tables I have to execute another query for each row. and the other problem is that I want to do pagination on my result but because my first table contain something like 15,15,15,15,14,14,.... I don't know how set limit and its offset :D. for example limit 20,0 may return 2 shops data or 2.5 shops. for now I working on combinations of these two methods. thank you all for your comments :)

Comment: @Soheil I would then believe the table structure should be re-engineered if that is possible, to fit the use case better. Or you may try to perform the pivotting (much) later if that can work.

Comment: @Romain I used `,group_concat(case when brand.name='{$brand['name']}' and category={$category['id']} then concat(color.name,':',num) end) as {$brand['name']}C` in my code after each sum and it done the trike :D

Answer (score 0):

I find out the answer and want to share it with others.
I added below code in my query after each sum

```
,group_concat(case when brand.name='{$brand['name']}' and category={$category['id']} then concat(color.name,':',num) end) as {$brand['name']}C
```

{$brand['name']} and {$category['id']} are variables in my php code for iterating between brands and categories
I don't know why it took so long for me to finding such an easy solution :P shame on me :D